# Query to retrieve the message thread

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a query that gets an entire message thread ordered by ascending and all the message threads are also ordered by ascending so it would look something like this

```
posted 5 days ago  
    posted 2 days ago
    posted 1 hour ago

posted 9 days ago
    posted 4 hours ago
    posted 2 hours ago

posted 20 days ago
    posted 7 days ago
```

I have been trying for a while and still cannot get the expected output.

I have the messages in each message thread ordered by desc but I cannot figure out how to order all of the messages by desc

[image]

How should I approach this? Should I first get the rootnodes of each message thread and use the thread_ids of those rootnodes to perform queries to then get the entire message thread? (like in non sql languages using a for loop)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function to get the date of the first post in a thread. Then you can order by that.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
             first_value(date_posted)
                OVER (PARTITION BY thread_id
                      ORDER BY is_root IS NOT TRUE) AS leader_date 
      FROM event_comments) AS comments_with_leaderdate
ORDER BY leader_date DESC, date_posted DESC;
```

This makes use of the fact that `FALSE < TRUE`.